# Mostrar varias columnas entre tablas foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas estoy intentando obtener la columna de un jugador con su respectivo equipo

Primero tengo la tabla jugador_tt

```
CREATE TABLE `jugador_tt` (
  `id` int(55) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_userwp` int(55) NOT NULL,
  `id_equipo` int(55) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `jugador_tt`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_userwp` (`id_userwp`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_equipo` (`id_equipo`);

ALTER TABLE `jugador_tt`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `jugador_tt_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_equipo`) REFERENCES `equipos` (`id`);
```

La otra tabla es equipos

```
CREATE TABLE `equipos` (
  `id` int(55) NOT NULL,
  `flag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_equipo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_jugador` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente como en **jugador_tt**

la columna **id_equipo** esta relacionada con la columna **id** de la tabla **equipos**

Quiero obtener todos los datos de la columna equipos pero desde **id_equipo** no se si me dejo entender.

Ya que quiero mostrar una lista de jugadores pero que se muestren a la vez sus equipos.

He probado usar la consulta

```
SELECT
  e.flag, e.nombre_equipo, j.nombre
FROM 
  equipos e

  LEFT JOIN jugador_tt j
```

Pero aún así no me arroja ningún resultado

Cualquier ayuda me vendria bien mas que nada para poder entender un poco mas. Muchas gracias.

PD: Estoy obteniendo los datos desde PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero hay una cosa que debo aclararte, en la **tabla equipo** no va el nombre del jugador, ya que la **tabla equipo** tiene un campo que sirve para establecer la relación con la **tabla jugador**, y de esa relación es que obtendrías el nombre del jugador:

```
select j.Nombre, e.Nombre
from jugador j inner join equipo e
on e.id = j.idEquipo;
```

En esta consulta se usa la **cláusula inner join** para juntar ambas tablas por los campos que se relacionan, a la **tabla jugador** se le da como **alias j** y a la **tabla equipos** se le da como **alias e**. Por último en la **cláusula select** se proyectarán los campos que desees, en este caso muestro el nombre del jugador y del equipo, pero tu puedes poner todos los que quieras siguiendo la notación:

```
tabla.Columna
```

Comment: hice lo que has escrito arriba en código y m efunciono, pero como lo que no entendi fue lo de abajo.

Otra cosa, yo tengo datos almacenados de jugadores en la tabla players, como puedo hacer para registrar esos jugadores en cada equipo

Es decir por ID? o Poniendo el nombre del Equipo en nombre_equipo, yo queria hacer algo parecido a las llaves foraneas pero no entiendo :(

Comment: @JoaqhoC, vamos por parte, que es lo de abajo?

Comment: tabla.Columna eso no entendi, ya hice lo de 

`SELECT j.Nombre, e.nombre_equipo, e.flag FROM jugador_tt j INNER JOIN equipos e on e.id = j.id_equipo;`

Y me dio el resultado de los jugadores con el equipo y el flag.

Comment: en el select ves como pones j.nombre, e.nombre, etc. Lo que quiero decir con tabla.columana es eso, es un ejemplo que generaliza. En j.nombre, la tabla es j y la columna es Nombre

Comment: Ah okas, bueno eso ya esta entonces. Ya lo he captado. Agradezco esa ayuda. Ahora estoy enredado con lo de los jugadores. :/ que no puedo idealizar como hacer que cada jugador este en un equipo, es decir si Jugador L. Messi esta en un equipo debe ser si o si un equipo que este registrado en la tabla de Equipos.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126056/japv entra aqui